# jquery load() works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

The following code works fine in firefox but not in chrome.. I'm not so familiar with jquery so please help me.

The ultimate aim is to change the content of a div with class="change" dynamically

```js
$(function(){
    $("#content").load("consulting.html");
  });
$(".change").click(function(){
  var page=$(this).attr('href');
  $("#content").load(page);
  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try launching chrome / chromium with **--allow-file-access-from-files** flag set.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent

Answer (score 0):

there is 3 possible answer:

- use `--allow-file-access-from-files` option
- use `--disable-web-security` option (not good option)
- use '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'

for how to use option on chrome see [website](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/)!